# ¿Como detectar el link en el que estoy con Selenium Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Lo que estoy buscando es una manera de poder detectar el link en el que estoy.

Ejemplo:

`si estoy en: google.es (continua con el código)`

`si no estoy en google.es (esperar hasta que lo esté)`

Lo pongo así por que no tengo ni idea de como empezar el código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para detectar la página que estas visitando bastaría con un:

```
driver.current_url
```

Este valor devuelve la URL en la que estás actualmente, y ya puedes hacer comprobaciones según tus necesidades

```
if driver.current_url == "https://google.es/":
        print("Estoy en Google.")
```